# What is the use of cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete for DockerBuilderPublisher in jenkins-pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using below code in jenkins pipeline to build docker image and push to custom artifactory registry.

```
step([
                $class: 'DockerBuilderPublisher', 
                cleanImages: true, 
                cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete: true, 
                cloud: 'docker-cloud', 
                dockerFileDirectory: '.', 
                pushCredentialsId: 'docker-jenkins-credential', 
                pushOnSuccess: true, 
                tagsString: "<docker-artifactory-repo>/<imagename>:<imagetag>"
            ])
```

Can someone explain what is the option `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete` does and what is the use?
Any documentation link for all the options available and meaning will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a real documentation about `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete`.

Official javadoc: [boolean cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/docker-plugin/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/builder/DockerBuilderPublisher.html#cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete)

The `DockerBuildPublisher.class` with all its members (also the `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete`) can be found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/builder/DockerBuilderPublisher.java). Unfortunately there is no javadoc for `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete` so we have to scan the code to see what it does.

If you blame the class you can see the commit where this member was introduced. The commit has a decent description: [Feature to delete images from repository when jenkins culls the job.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/commit/f1cde20fa6dcd27cd06543b853fd3b3de2f72440)

The commit introduced a new class [DockerRunListener](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/listener/DockerRunListener.java) that executes logic if `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete` is true.

The current master-branch (see this one: [DockerRunListener](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/listener/DockerRunListener.java)) has the code section disabled (was done in this [commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/commit/b1377e7bca80c6be49668e4d114469736d6b9262)) so my guess is `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete` does nothing?

```
@Override
    public void onDeleted(Run<?, ?> run) {
        super.onDeleted(run);
        List<DockerBuildImageAction> actions = run.getActions(DockerBuildImageAction.class);

    for(DockerBuildImageAction action : actions) {
        if( action.cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete ) {
            LOGGER.info("Attempting to clean up docker image for " + run);


            if( action.pushOnSuccess ) {

                // TODO:

                /*
                DockerRegistryClient registryClient;
                try {
                    Identifier identifier = Identifier.fromCompoundString(action.taggedId);
                    registryClient = DockerRegistryClient.builder()
                            .withUrl(identifier.repository.getURL())
                            .build();
                    registryClient.registryApi().deleteRepositoryTag("library",
                            identifier.repository.getPath(),
                            identifier.tag.orNull());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Failed to clean up", ex);
                }
                      */
            }
        }
}
```

I checked the git repo and I can confirm this is the only spot where logic was executed if `cleanupWithJenkinsJobDelete` was set to true.